# Laravel 5.5 wont install with php7

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, laravel-5.5

I try to install Laravel 5.5 version so I run command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel test 5.5.*
```

but I got this error:

[image]

If you see the top of image I run command `php -v` and its clear that version i 7.0.27

How to solve my issue?

Comment: This is becouse may be your system doesn't satisfy server requirements check https://laravel.com/docs/5.5

Answer (score 2):

You can try to update your composer:

```
composer update
```

Or try to use the full php7 path, example:

```
/path/to/your/php7 composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel test 5.5.*
```

Answer (score 1):

Seem your XAMPP not installed properly. Uninstall existing XAMPP and manually delete the entire folder. (take backup of htdocs if there s some files as well PHPmyadmin DB backups). And [download XAMPP from here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) and install it.

1. Install composer

and run this

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test
```

> **It's PHP7, so composer install Laravel 5.5 or higher by-default**

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and the problem was that an after php upgrade there was still two php versions running almost together, so, in my case composer was using one version of php and laravel use the other. To solve that problem i uninstalled all php versions, update my php repositories and then i made a fresh install of php, composer and laravel. 
Nowadays I have laravel 5.5 running with php 7.2 and i added laravel in enviroment variables so when i need to creaste a new project i use `laravel new project_name` 
Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify a version for project

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test
```

Comment: No it will install the latest version

Comment: I try and for me install 5.4 vesiob

Answer (score -1):

By any chance is the PHP require value in composer.json not `"php": ">=7.0.0"`

Try adding --prefer-dist and remove 5.5.*

Comment: improve your answer

Answer (score -2):

Laravel requires PHP >= 7.0.0, you currently have version 5.6.

Install a newer version of PHP or use homestead.

Comment: But please see the image - I have version 7... (look at the top of image - where I run command php -v)

Comment: improve your answer